# Edittext: Start input at last column automatically

Tags: android, android-edittext

If I start my Activity, I want to get the place for Input at the end of the text in the edittext. Now it is at the beginning, but if a user edits the text, it should go at the end

Sorry for my broken English, I am German.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
    EditText editText=findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```